# Selecting by feature

Tags: qgis, features

I get an error message:
"Input layer A contains invalid geometries (Feature 33). Unable to complete intersection algorithm" with the intersect tool.

Now I want to have a look at Feature 33. How can I select it? Apparently the ID doesn't correspond to the feature number.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Take a look at https://anitagraser.com/2017/08/29/fixing-invalid-polygon-geometries/ for fixing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the validity check tool (`vector > Geometry tools >  check validity` ) to check the type of error in the geometry and where (feature) it is.